# is there a good way to save socket.io message history

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

I want to record socket.io message history, i.e. the contents of two users talked, for later use. Is there some socket.io built-in functions to realize this, or if not, what is a good way to realize it?

Answer (score 11):

First of, you need some way to identify the users with a unique id that does not disappear when the user disconnects, like a username or an email address.

All the messages in the conversation should then somehow be stored on the server, like in a "chat-object" for the conversation between the two users.

Either periodically, when the user disconnects, or every time a the "chat-object" changes (eg. a new message is sent), save the "chat-object" in a database of any sort you like. You can use JSON to serialize the "chat-object", save it in any way you like (eg. a custom file, a mysql database, or whatever). To serialize an object, use the code below on the node server:

```
var chatString = JSON.stringify(theChatObject);
```

Save the string together with the two users' unique IDs. So when a new conversation is started between the same two people. You can just go to your file or database and retrieve the old chatobject, and unserialize it with the following code.

```
var oldChat = JSON.parse(theRetrievedChatString);
```

Comment: So, will it cause too much overhead if I try to save "chat-object" into database(i.e. mongodb) each time a new message is created?

Comment: "too much" depends on how much load the server will experience. If it is an issue, it could help to look at other options. But still, saving it into a database every time can be beneficial, since it decreases the risk of messages getting lost.